# Magento - Ignore controller or action in ReferrerUrl

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a problem with redirectReferrer()
When I add a product in cart, I do it with ajax (call : http://wwwww.ww/quickview/product/add).
Until here, everything is ok.

But, if I want to remove product from my cart, the `deleteAction()` redirect me to `http://wwwww.ww/quickview/product/add` with the method `$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));`

Is it possible to ignore a whole Controller or just an Action in `_redirectReferer`, without any modification in the `deleteAction()` ??

I tried this `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setNoReferer(true);`, but it not seems to work..

Thank you.
PS: Magento CE 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that is inside my controller (and action), that the referrer is setted ...

I return in JSON:
 `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml')->toHtml();`

I think this is this part who cause my issue..